# Is there a built-in way to parse standard escape sequences in a user-supplied string in C?

Tags: c

In C, if I put a literal string like `"Hello World \n\t\x90\x53"` into my code, the compiler will parse the escape sequences into the correct bytes and leave the rest of characters alone.

If the above string is instead supplied by the user, either on the command line or in a file, is there a way to invoke the compiler's functionality to get the same literal bytes into a `char[]`?

Obviously I could manually implement the functionality by hardcoding the [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C), but I would prefer not to do that if I can just invoke some compiler library instead.

Comment: There is certainly some source code out there which does what you are asking for, but I'm not aware that you could use the compiler's function for that; you also can't use the C compiler's C source code parsing functions.

Comment: Fortunately, the hard-coded escape sequences is not a long list. I've done this, and similar things, hundreds of times. (Well, maybe not *hundreds*, but it comes down to a pretty basic `switch` on each character and is written in a couple of minutes.)

Comment: It is not so hard to put this into a function ("hardcode" ?) Also: multiple variants of this function could co-exist: One that also recognises octal escapes, and one that does not, et cetera.

Comment: @Jongware: I mostly end up with some kind of state machine, adding a bunch of gotos for fun ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no standard function to do that.

A suggestion for a non-standard library solution is to use [glib's](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) [`g_strcompress()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strcompress) function.

Comment: Do you know why? What standard libraries is that including? This answer is not useful as it only tells the OP "at least one person on the internet thinks not. So keep looking."

Comment: "Expert opinion" :) Now it's "at least one person" +1

Comment: @djechlin "The standard library" is a well-defined library, it doesn't mean "a common library", it means the library that comes standard with the C programming language (home of `printf()` and so on).

Comment: @unwind I'd go as far as saying "it is the library (or libraries) defined in the standard". That means that, for me, I try to make sure to be aware of "the standard library" and "the POSIX libraries".